# woocommerce - get all purchased items of a product id or category and joined with info for all purchasers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need a query that will retrieve all completed purchases for a particular product category or id and join that with the purchaser's (not current users) info of all people that purchased the product.

From an application perspective, think of it like a recall for a specific product.  I need to get all info for the purchaser's of that item to notify them of an issue.

I'm new to wordpress/woocommerce, but have years of programming experience.  My database skills are weak, though.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try anything ?

Comment: Yes, to a point.  I have a single side wpdb query that gets me all the purchased product posts, BUT since those posts were made by the admin, it's the admin data I'm getting back.  
I've also tried a get_posts($args) call, but it keeps coming back as error on line 691 of deprecated functions.  The args I'm using I found online that are supposed to get all the purchased products of a category, but since it doesn't work, I'm not sure what other information would come in that query.
So, I'm essentially starting from scratch looking for the right solution.

Comment: The args used so far: $args = array('post_type' => 'shop_order',  
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // or -1 for all  
            'tax_query' => array(  
              'relation' => 'AND', 
              array( 'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',  
                  'field' => 'slug', 
                  'terms' => 'wc-completed'  ),
              array(  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
                'field' => 'id', 
                'terms' => $prod_cat ) 
            ) 
      );